# How to create a singleton service in angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a service called MessageService, I want to make it singleton.

```
 @Injectable()
  export class MessageService {
  name: string ;
  constructor() { 
     this.name = "Marouen"; 
   }

}
```

but I realize that every time the service is called from a component it create a new instance.

Comment: And how did you realize that? If you set the name in one component, you can get the value in the other...

Comment: All services are `singleton` in Angular.

Comment: @PardeepJain not totally true. If you provide the same service in two different lazy modules, there will be two instances.

Comment: @ChristianBenseler agree !!, But I was talking about normal flow

Comment: Here is the link to the angular doc with multiple service instances: https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#scenario-multiple-edit-sessions . Quote: "Recall that every component instance has its own injector. Providing the service at the component level ensures that every instance of the component gets its own, private instance of the service."

Answer (score 1):

Try to provide service at module level (app.module.ts etc) and not at the component level.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  providers: [MessageService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Also make sure that this module that provides service is not lazy loaded module.